# inActiveTintColor not working in tabbar react native

Tags: android, react-native, tabbar

I'm using this library :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-nav-tab-bar

And I have written code like this :

```
const Tabs = AnimatedTabBarNavigator();

function Tabbar1(props) {

    return (

        <Tabs.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeBackgroundColor: "#ff00ff",
                inactiveBackgroundColor: '#000000',
                activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
                inactiveTintColor: '#000000',
                showIcon: true,
            }}
        >
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="Dashboard"
                component={Dashboard}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="Services"
                component={Services}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="Notification"
                component={Notification}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="More"
                component={More}
            />
        </Tabs.Navigator>

    );
}

export default withNavigation(Tabbar1)
```

But the inactiveBackgroundColor or inactiveTintColor not working here,

[image]

So can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When I examined the repository, I saw that there was no inactiveBackgroundColor feature. If you remove this feature and use different colors, maybe you can explore. Also, as stated in the appearence prop, the default of tabBarBackground is set to "white". You have to change it to do what you want.